# why are executables installed with homebrew trusted on MacOS?

Tags: macos, homebrew, osx-gatekeeper, notarize

I have a stupid question about homebrew: Why are executables that I install via homebrew trusted by MacOS (gatekeeper)? i.e. after installation I can run an executable and don't get a security popup and don't have to allow an exception - why is that?

I initially thought that homebrew might sign/notarize the binaries in their CI, but looking at some random executables it doesn't look like they have a signature: `spctl -a -v $(which <some-executable-installed-with-homebrew>)`.

edit: meaning executables installed from bottles (pre-compiled binaries, not source packages compiled on my local machine)

Comment: This is arguably a question that would be better suited to [apple.se] (the Stack Exchange site dedicated to questions about Apple products, without the scoping limitation to development questions only that applies here) in its current form. It might be modifiable to be clearly on topic here ("how can I make my own build/install process behave like Homebrew's?"), but it isn't in that form now.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com) or [su].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no quarantining flag for a CLI app downloaded with curl.
Home-brew, uses UNIX core tools to download the bottles, and thus they don't have this flag set.

Next home-brew also ad-hoc signs binaries.

Don't confuse code sign with notarisation.

Notarisation is where Apple vouches for software signed *with a dev cert private key*.

They cannot notarise ad-hoc signed software (like home-brew bottles) by definition.

> Now when my executable is NOT notarized it terminates with "Killed: 9", regardless if there's a quarantine attribute or not.

This is happening, I would speculate because the binary here **isnt** ad-hoc signed. Nothing to do with notarisation.

I bet you are on Apple Silicon right?